# Wireless touch screen monitor

Tags: wireless-networking, display, touchscreen

Does anyone make a wireless touch screen monitor that would be could be used kind of like a tablet pc?

Basically I want something that could sit on my lap and allow me to view and control a nearby pc.

UPDATE:
Anyone know of a touch screen tablet pc without a keyboard, so it's just a screen?

Answer (score 6):

You may use this ARM-based [**Touch Book**](http://www.alwaysinnovating.com/home/index.htm) by AlwaysInnovating (from $299) and control your 'nearby PC' via VNC.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

any tablet pc could run a vnc client and utilize the remote desktop connection to control your pc through a home network.

chicken of the vnc is a good client and can control both mac and windows.

Also mimo makes a usb touch screen monitor that could in theory be connected to a wireless usb or bluetooth extender.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an Wireless Touch Screen Monitor availble now. It is made by Soundgraph, it is a touch screen USB monitor which is made wireless using an USB device. It is known as FingerVU Wireless Monitor Set. Check the website for Pics, Videos & price. I hope the information is helpfull to all although it came late.

Harneet Barmy